# Adding an image breaks my navbar dropdown

Tags: html, css

I am creating a site for someone. At the top, I have a bar with links and a dropdown menu, and a logo on the left. For some reason, the image keeps on messing up the dropdown. It is fully functional, but visually is messed up. To see what I mean, hover over the dropdown, the button expands beyond the bar.

I have tried wrapping the image in a div, setting margins and padding for the image, and using a different image, none of which worked. If I point the image to an invalid URL, it works, but obviously I want a real image.

Code:

```js
function hide(element) {
  element.className += " hidden";
}

function unhide(element) {
  element.className = element.className.replace(/\bhidden\b/, "");
}

function toggle(button) {
  var list = document.getElementById(button.getAttribute("data-list"));
  (list.className.search(/\bhidden\b/) > -1) ? unhide(list): hide(list);
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches(".drop-button") && !e.target.matches(".drop-choices")) {
      hide(list);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#back-top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#bar-top {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-option {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 0;
}

.drop-button {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.nav-option:hover,
.nav-option:active,
.nav-option:focus,
.drop-button:hover,
.drop-button:active,
.drop-button:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}

.drop-choices {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 140px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.drop-choices p {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  width: 188px;
  text-align: left;
}

.drop-choices p:hover,
.drop-choices p:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}

p.drop-title {
  cursor: initial;
}

p.drop-title:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Home - Jessica Keirns</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="topbar.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="back-top">
    <div id="bar-top">
      <a href="/main.xhtml" class="nav-link">
        <img src="https://www.thsp.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Icon-Placeholder.png" alt="Home" width="40px" height="40px" />
      </a>
      <div class="nav-option drop-down" data-list="test" onclick="toggle(this)">
        <button class="drop-button">Dropdown</button>
        <div id="test" class="drop-choices hidden">
          <p tabindex="0" id="choice1">choice1</p>
          <p tabindex="0" id="choice2">choice2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="/about.xhtml" class="nav-option nav-link">About Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="drop.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to make the alignment in the middle.

But, I would not recommend you code use css style how you have used. you should [study](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) about `table`, `table-row`, `inline-block` and `table-cell` before you start it. Because table should be in a proper format like `table-cell` should only inside `table-row` and `table-row` should only inside `table`. if you are getting confusion just use `inline-block` which is pretty easy to understand

```js
function hide(element) {
  element.className += " hidden";
}

function unhide(element) {
  element.className = element.className.replace(/\bhidden\b/, "");
}

function toggle(button) {
  var list = document.getElementById(button.getAttribute("data-list"));
  (list.className.search(/\bhidden\b/) > -1) ? unhide(list): hide(list);
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches(".drop-button") && !e.target.matches(".drop-choices")) {
      hide(list);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#back-top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#bar-top {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-option {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 0;
}

.drop-button {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.nav-option:hover,
.nav-option:active,
.nav-option:focus,
.drop-button:hover,
.drop-button:active,
.drop-button:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}

.drop-choices {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 140px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.drop-choices p {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  width: 188px;
  text-align: left;
}

.drop-choices p:hover,
.drop-choices p:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}

p.drop-title {
  cursor: initial;
}

p.drop-title:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Home - Jessica Keirns</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="topbar.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="back-top">
    <div id="bar-top">
      <a href="/main.xhtml" class="nav-link">
        <img src="https://www.thsp.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Icon-Placeholder.png" alt="Home" width="40px" height="40px" />
      </a>
      <div class="nav-option drop-down" data-list="test" onclick="toggle(this)">
        <button class="drop-button">Dropdown</button>
        <div id="test" class="drop-choices hidden">
          <p tabindex="0" id="choice1">choice1</p>
          <p tabindex="0" id="choice2">choice2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="/about.xhtml" class="nav-option nav-link">About Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="drop.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I hadn't been aware of `table-row`. I had found similar code to this somewhere, and based my code off of it. Thanks for the information, I'll try it soon. Does `inline-block` place elements in a row? I hadn't been aware of that, so I didn't try it.

Comment: @PorygonZRocks sorry I forgot to update the css in snippet. now i updated it

Answer (score 1):

I used a flexbox to align the header content properly.

```js
function hide(element) {
  element.className += " hidden";
}

function unhide(element) {
  element.className = element.className.replace(/\bhidden\b/, "");
}

function toggle(button) {
  var list = document.getElementById(button.getAttribute("data-list"));
  (list.className.search(/\bhidden\b/) > -1) ? unhide(list): hide(list);
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches(".drop-button") && !e.target.matches(".drop-choices")) {
      hide(list);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#back-top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#bar-top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 50px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-option {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.drop-button {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.nav-option:hover,
.nav-option:active,
.nav-option:focus,
.drop-button:hover,
.drop-button:active,
.drop-button:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}

.drop-choices {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgray;
  min-width: 140px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.drop-choices p {
  color: black;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  width: 188px;
  text-align: left;
}

.drop-choices p:hover,
.drop-choices p:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
}

p.drop-title {
  cursor: initial;
}

p.drop-title:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="back-top">
  <div id="bar-top">
    <a href="/main.xhtml" class="nav-link">
      <img src="https://www.thsp.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Icon-Placeholder.png" alt="Home" width="40px" height="40px" />
    </a>
    <div class="nav-option drop-down" data-list="test" onclick="toggle(this)">
      <button class="drop-button">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="test" class="drop-choices hidden">
        <p tabindex="0" id="choice1">choice1</p>
        <p tabindex="0" id="choice2">choice2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/about.xhtml" class="nav-option nav-link">About Me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but I chose the other answer because it was more backwards-compatible. I'd suggest this for anyone if ie compatibility is not required.